# How can I get LaTeX fonts into Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, font-management, latex

I am currently trying to add equations created with LaTeXiT straight into Adobe Illustrator CS6, but somehow the "font" changes. I've tried scrolling around the Internet to see if I could find out how to change this but without luck. Is there anybody who knows how to fix this problem so I get my LaTeX fonts into Illustrator?

I am working on a Mac.

Comment: This has been technically asked before here: [How do I edit PDF files produced by LaTeX in Illustrator? Fonts are not found](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45256/how-do-i-edit-pdf-files-produced-by-latex-in-illustrator-fonts-are-not-found); also a quick Google search resulted this: [Combining LaTeX and Illustrator](http://www.latex-community.org/know-how/latexs-friends/61-latexs-friends-others/381-combining-latex-and-illustrator)

Comment: [Our text stack side in regards to fonts.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts)

Comment: You might want to look into getting the OpenType version of Latin Modern --- I believe that one can now typeset using it in (La)TeX which will then allow transparent editing.

Answer (score 1):

## LaTeX Fonts Are All Royalty Free Fonts

Look at this list here. https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb27-2/tb87hagen-gyre.pdf

And more reading material here https://www.tug.org/fonts/deutsch-urw.txt

> URW++ 35 Core PostScript Fonts  The German digital typefoundry URW++
> Design and Development released a commercial-quality set of 5 base
> PostScript fonts, expanded to include the complete 315-character Adobe
> PostScript 3 character set. The fonts are available under both the
> Aladdin Free Public License and the GNU General Public License. Their
> license notice explicitly allows embedding in PostScript and PDF
> documents. The fonts with the GNU General Public License are available
> with the GNU Ghostscript 6.0 or later.

Search for the font you want from that list using Google. They are hosted on multiple websites

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the font.

Find the font where you have download it double click on it and it should open the font in another window. So there you have on top left corner install button.

After it is install open Illustrator and search for it in font section.

Comment: LaTeX fonts are generally not regular fonts that can be installed as a system font, so this answer likely doesn’t really help much.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet LaTeX fonts are regular fonts. What else would they be?

Comment: @LateralTerminal: LaTeX has its own, very distinctive, flavour of fonts. What you find with a very casual Google search can be *anything*: a metafont definition, a bitmap rendition, a Type 1 font in TeX' own unique encoding (as good as useless for more general Unicode-based software), and/or an OTF version of such font (useless for the same reason).

Comment: @usr2564301 That's not entirely true. https://fileinfo.com/extension/tfm

Comment: @usr2564301 also read my answer. The fonts are open source. You can get the fonts in non TFM format and use them in illustrator. That's what he wants.